# What is the difference between assigning prototype to Object.create prototype

Tags: javascript, oop, object, inheritance, prototype

I don't seem to understand the difference between assigning one constructor prototype to an other, and using Object.create.
can anyone provide an example of the difference?

I've created this inheritance example which provides the same result for both cases:

```
function MyObject() {
}

function O1() {
   MyObject.call(this);
}

O1.prototype = MyObject.prototype;

function O2() {
    MyObject.call(this);
}

O2.prototype = Object.create(MyObject.prototype);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `Object.create` just creates one mode (superfluous) object. If you create `new O1` and `new O2`, their inheritance diagram will be this:

[image]

Comment: Thank-you, I was looking for an example scenario for  each implementation? (to better understand when to use each method of implementation) 
MDN uses the "O2" implementation by default. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model)

Comment: @ShaiKimchi: the best way is to use just `Object.create` and don't fiddle with prototypes. `Function.prototype` and `new` are not very idiomatic in Javascript, see http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html